unable to read files from local machine using docker and kubernetes deployment yaml file
I am using minikube to test the kubernetes. Below is my dockerfile and deployment file. I have 2 volumes mounted. I have deployment the image using below yaml file. The cluster and image is working fine and running. but only 1 issue is that below configuration is unable to read and write files to local system from given path. Files are inside these folders
Dockerfile
FROM openjdk:17-jdk-alpine
ARG JARFILE=target/*.jar
COPY ./target/zion-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar app.jar
VOLUME /home/ubuntu/yd/
VOLUME /etc/dost/yd/
ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar", "/app.jar"]

and below is my deployment yaml file
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: deploymentlocal
spec:
  replicas: 2
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: dep
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: dep
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: dep-container
          image: java17dep
          imagePullPolicy: Never
          ports:
            - containerPort: 8080
          livenessProbe:
            httpGet:
              path: /v3/test/db
              port: 8080
            initialDelaySeconds: 60
            periodSeconds: 60
            timeoutSeconds: 5
          volumeMounts:
            - name: yd-volume
              mountPath: /home/ubuntu/yd
            - name: z-volume
              mountPath: /etc/dost/yd
      volumes:
        - name: yd-volume
          hostPath:
            path: /home/ubuntu/yd
        - name: z-volume
          hostPath:
            path: /etc/dost/yd


can you tell whats wrong in these. I am unable to read and write files to local system from given path.
Thanks in advance

Containers, and especially Kubernetes, can't read and write the local system.  A hostPath: type volume refers to the (remote, arbitrary) node the container is running on.  If you need to access local files, Kubernetes isn't the right tool, and Docker may not be either.

Thanks @DavidMaze: But from only with docker i can read and wrire to host system. Unable to do it with kubernetes. The command used to run the container is ```
docker run --name java17zion8082 -v /home/ubuntu/yd:/home/ubuntu/yd -v /etc/dost/yd:/etc/dost/yd -p 8082:8080 -d java17zion


Why do you want this to run in Kubernetes (normally a clustered environment)?  What's in the local files, that the container needs to access them?

@DavidMaze: As there are some config files in host machine, that is required.

The (remote) cluster can't access them.  Do you need to put them into a ConfigMap instead?

@DavidMaze: No, it tried using hostPath only.

As DavidMaze suggested, Kubernetes is not the right tool to access local files. A hostPath volume mounts a file or directory from the host node's file system into your Pod. Using the hostPath volume type presents many security risks. If you can avoid using a hostPath volume, you should. Instead you can use local PersistentVolume.
If you allow a read-write mount of any host path by an untrusted Pod, the containers in that Pod may be able to subvert the read-write host mount.
You need to take care when using hostPath volumes, whether these are mounted as read-only or as read-write, because:

Access to the host filesystem can expose privileged system credentials (such as for the kubelet) or privileged APIs (such as the container runtime socket), that can be used for container escape or to attack other parts of the cluster.

Pods with identical configuration (such as created from a PodTemplate) may behave differently on different nodes due to different files on the nodes.



I am looking forward to your feedback to understand whether the provided resolution has helped you in resolving the issue. If not, I am happy to assist further
